# How to get the correct XPATH CSS on airbnb website

Tags: php, laravel, xpath, phantomjs

Halo everyone. now im learnin XPATH function for scraping airbnb website. i combine  it with PHP PhantomJS in Laravel 5.1.

base on this airbnb site : https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/1064946

i want to get the hotel name and the price. but i confuse how to set the correct css in my xpath code. here is my code :

```
    $client = Client::getInstance();
    $request = $client->getMessageFactory()->createRequest('https://www.airbnb.com/rooms/1064946', 'GET');
    $response = $client->getMessageFactory()->createResponse();
    $client->send($request,$response);
    $htmlstr = $response->getContent();
    $dom = new DOMDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($htmlstr);
    $xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);
    $entries = [];

    foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="with-new-header has-epcot-header"]') as $node) {
              $entries[] = [
               'hotel_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(//div[@class="_12ei9u44"])',$node),
               'price' => $xpath->evaluate('string(//div[@class="_doc79r"])',$node)
             ];
    }
    var_dump($entries);
```

but the result is

```
array(0) { }
```

what wrong with this code. please help me. thank you

Comment: what is var_dump($page) ?

Comment: debug. like print() or echo

Comment: i am demanding output of var_dump($page), what I meant here is where does page variable came from in @$dom->loadHTML($page) ?

Comment: ahh. i got your point. but i already fix it. but still not success. i change itu into @$dom->loadHTML($htmlstr );

Comment: remove backslash behind DOMXPath($dom)

Comment: @RahulGurung i need to use that. because im using laravel 5.1,, if not. the result will be this  "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\DOMXPath' not found"

Comment: ah ! I don't know DOMXPath but I suggest you to debug it up to down using var_dump to figure out in which line it messes things up .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check the various tag elements and classes your using, the ones you have all seem to be looking for things that I can't find.  I have managed to extract some of the data, but as I'm not using Laravel this may affect it...

```
foreach ($xpath->query('//div[@class="_1kzvqab3"]') as $node) {
    $entries[] = [
        'hotel_name' => $xpath->evaluate('string(//span[@class="_12ei9u44"])', $node),
        'price' => $xpath->evaluate('string(//span[@class="_doc79r"])', $node)
    ];
}
```

One useful thing I've found is to write the HTML to a temporary file which I can then check the contents of, something like...

```
file_put_contents("out.html", $htmlstr);
```

I can then use this to check what the code is actually running against and see what tags and classes are being used.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a class that doesn't belong to a div:

```
//div[@class="with-new-header has-epcot-header"]
```

It belongs to the body:

```
//body[@class="with-new-header has-epcot-header"]
```

Also the following xpath statements are not divs either:

```
//div[@class="_12ei9u44"]
//div[@class="_doc79r"]
```

They are spans:

```
//span[@class="_12ei9u44"]
//span[@class="_doc79r"]
```

Are you seeing the pattern?  You don't just start a xpath with div, it's the tag.